# How to use wc and piping to find how many files and directories are in a certain directory?

Tags: scripting, find, wc, file-types

How can I use word counter (`wc`) and piping to count how many files or directories are in the `/usr/bin` directory?

Comment: This homework?? It's OK to ask for help, just identify it as such, if it is.

Comment: yes it is but I post here to get an idea on how to achieve something since I'm new to Linux and it can be very complicated. And I already solve the question above with this command

Comment: ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | wc -

Comment: np. It's perfectly fine to ask for help! Just label it so people know, everyone here is usually happy to help people that are trying to learn the finer points of Unix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach would be to make use of `ls` to give us a list of the files, but we want this list to be guaranteed to show only 1 file or directory per line. The `-1` switch will do this for us.

```
$ ls -1
dir1
dir2
dir3
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

#### Example

Create the above sample data in an empty directory.

```
$ mkdir dir{1..3}
$ touch file{A..C}
```

Check it:

```
$ ls
dir1  dir2  dir3  fileA  fileB  fileC
```

Now to count you can use `wc -l` to count the number of lines, which correspond to a file or directory in the `ls -1` output.

```
$ ls -1 | wc -l
6
```

(note however that it doesn't include the hidden files)

#### Counting files or directories, just not together

To count either files or directories you need to change your tactic slightly. In this case I'd use `ls -l` since it shows what's a directory and what's a a file.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 16 09:48 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 16 09:48 dir2
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 16 09:48 dir3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 16 09:49 fileA
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 16 09:49 fileB
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 16 09:49 fileC
```

Then we can use `grep` to filter out directories or not-directories like so:

```
# directories
$ ls -l | grep "^d"
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 16 09:48 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 16 09:48 dir2
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 16 09:48 dir3

# regular files
$ ls -l | grep "^-"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 16 09:49 fileA
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 16 09:49 fileB
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 16 09:49 fileC
```

Now just use `wc -l` again to count the above:

```
# directories
$ ls -l | grep "^d" | wc -l
3

# regular files
$ ls -l | grep "^-" | wc -l
3
```

Though, you can avoid `wc` altogether, and use `grep`'s `-c` option:

```
$ ls -l | grep -c '^d'
```

(again, hidden files are not included. Note that directories and regular are two types of files. There are many more like named pipes, symbolic links, devices, sockets...).

#### Recursion

If you need to find the files and directories recursively under `/usr/bin` then you'll likely want to change tactics entirely and make use of another tool called `find`.

#### Example

```
$ find /usr/bin | wc -l
4632
```

(though above `/usr/bin` itself is included in the count)

The same techniques I used above could be employed use `ls` to do something similar but `ls` is generally not a good tool to parse the output. `find` on the other hand was built for this, and offers switches to find either files or directories.

```
# find files
$ find /usr/bin -type f

# find directories
$ find /usr/bin -type d
```

(note that this time, `find` is including hidden files (except `.` and `..`)).

#### newlines?

I've never figured out why a newline character is a legal character to use when creating file names or directory names. So the methods discussed above using `wc` and `ls` would not contend with these, so use them with that in mind.

#### Example

Create a directory & file name with newlines.

```
$ mkdir $'dir4\n5'
$ touch $'fileD\nE'
```

`ls` shows them correctly:

```
$ ls -1
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4?5
fileA
fileB
fileC
fileD?E
```

But `wc` counts the directories and files that contain newlines as 2 items, not one.

```
$ ls -1 | wc -l
10
```

One method to get around this, if using the GNU implementation of `find` is to make use of `find`'s ability to print something else in place of each file that it finds and then count those instead.

#### Example

```
$ find . -printf . | wc -c
9
```

Here we're finding everything in the current directory (except `..`), and printing a dot (`.`) for each, and then counting the dots using `wc`'s ability to count bytes instead of lines, `wc -c`.

#### References

- [bash - What is the best way to count find-results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663607/bash-what-is-the-best-way-to-count-find-results)

Comment: While files in `/usr/bin` are all going to be well-formatted (and also won't contain spaces, so technically you could even just `echo * | wc -w`), it's worth noting that all of these will break on filenames containing newlines.

Comment: @evilsoup - no I don't believe the `ls -l` or `ls -1` will break b/c we're counting lines, not words! The `find` may break, but again, we're counting lines not words.

Comment: What I mean is that this will (I think, I'm on Windows right now so I can't test) break if the files contain *newlines*. So `touch $'foo\nbar'` within an empty directory followed by one of your commands (say `ls -1 | wc -l`) will report two files rather than one -- because that one file is two lines as far as `wc` is concerned. Unless `ls` replaces newlines with some other character (I don't think it does, but again I'm not in a position to test right now).

Comment: @evilsoup - correct, newline char. is a legal char. for file names, and the methods would not be able to contend with those types of filenames correctly.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - is `wc -c` an issue when counting the periods?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - OK, when YOU give feedback I try to read it 4-5 times to make sure I understand the point and to make sure what I'm doing 110% conforms with what you're telling me 8-).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas is that true of *all* versions of `ls`? I think that those which *don't* output one line at a time to pipes automatically probably won't have the `-1` option -- so *these* commands will return an error rather than silently providing the wrong information, as a plain `ls` would.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get a break down of the number of each type of file recursively under some dir, with GNU `find`, you could do:

```
find /some/dir/. ! -name . -printf '%y\n' | sort | uniq -c | sed '
  s/f/regular files/;t
  s/d/directories/;t
  s/l/symbolic links/;t
  s/s/Unix domain sockets/;t
  s/b/block devices/;t
  s/c/character devices/;t
  s/p/FIFOs/;t
  s/D/Doors/;t
  s/n/network special files/;t
  s/.$/others (&)/'
```

On `/usr/bin` on my system, that gives:

```
   3727 regular files
    710 symbolic links
```

On `/dev`:

```
     83 block devices
    203 character devices
     31 directories
    426 symbolic links
      1 FIFOs
      1 Unix domain sockets
```

For symlinks, if you'd rather count them as the type of the file they point to rather than `symbolic links`, you can change it to:

```
find /some/dir/. ! -name . -printf '%Y\n' | sort | uniq -c | sed '
  s/f/regular files/;t
  s/d/directories/;t
  s/N/broken symbolic links/;t
  s/s/Unix domain sockets/;t
  s/b/block devices/;t
  s/c/character devices/;t
  s/p/FIFOs/;t
  s/D/Doors/;t
  s/n/network special files/;t
  s/.$/others (&)/'
```

Which now gives for my `/usr/bin`:

```
      1 directories
   4434 regular files
      2 broken symbolic links
```

(a broken symlink is a symlink to a file for which `find` cannot determine the type either because the file doesn't exist, or is in a directory you don't have access to or there's a loop in the resolution of the path of the file. In my case, those 2 where symlinks to files that are now gone).

None of those count `.` and `..`. If you wanted them included (why would you?), there's no other way with `find` than assume they're there for every directory and count them systematically:

```
find /some/dir/. -printf '%y\n' \( -name . -printf 'd\n' -o \
  -type d -printf 'd\nd\n' \)  | sort | uniq -c | sed '
  s/f/regular files/;t
  s/d/directories/;t
  s/l/symbolic links/;t
  s/s/Unix domain sockets/;t
  s/b/block devices/;t
  s/c/character devices/;t
  s/p/FIFOs/;t
  s/D/Doors/;t
  s/n/network special files/;t
  s/.$/others (&)/'
```

Which then gives on my `/usr/bin`:

```
      2 directories
   3727 regular files
    710 symbolic links
```

If you don't have access to the GNU `find`, you can rewrite the first one as:

```
find /some/dir/. ! -name . \( \
  -type f -exec printf '%.0sregular files\n' {} + -o \
  -type d -exec printf '%.0sdirectories\n' {} + -o \
  -type l -exec printf '%.0ssymbolic links\n' {} + -o \
  -type s -exec printf '%.0sUnix domain sockets\n' {} + -o \
  -type b -exec printf '%.0sblock devices\n' {} + -o \
  -type c -exec printf '%.0scharacter devices\n' {} + -o \
  -type p -exec printf '%.0sFIFOs\n' {} + -o \
  -exec printf '%.0sothers\n' {} + \) | sort | uniq -c
```

Now, strictly speaking, we've not been counting *files* but *directory entries*. A directory like `/usr/bin` typically has several entries that point to the same file. For instance, here, I have:

```
$ ls -lid /usr/bin/{nvi,nview,nex}
672252 -rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 434616 May 25 07:40 /usr/bin/nex
672252 -rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 434616 May 25 07:40 /usr/bin/nvi
672252 -rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 434616 May 25 07:40 /usr/bin/nview
```

Those are 3 directory entries (aka file names aka hard links) to the same file (the one with inode 672252. To count files instead of directory entries and with GNU `find` and GNU `uniq` (ignoring `.` and `..` files which anyway are hard links to other directories):

```
find /some/dir/. ! -name . -printf '%y\t%D:%i\n' |
  sort -u |
  cut -f1 |
  uniq -c |
  sed '
    s/f/regular files/;t
    s/d/directories/;t
    s/l/symbolic links/;t
    s/s/Unix domain sockets/;t
    s/b/block devices/;t
    s/c/character devices/;t
    s/p/FIFOs/;t
    s/d/Doors/;t
    s/n/network special files/;t
    s/.$/others (&)/'
```

On my `/usr/bin`, that gives:

```
   3711 regular files
    710 symbolic links
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said if you want all the file under /usr/bin recursively or just under the first level. Also, how are you going to get the  words that you are counting?
The usual way to find out is to run find into wc. Like this:
find /usr/bin | wc -l
Find will list everything there, directories & files. Wc -l will count all the lines in the find output. Is this a class assignment? It's ok if it is but I was wondering why you needed this info so that I could tailor the response more carefully.
Please let me know if you need more.
Costa

Answer (score 0):

In bash, without external tools.

```
cd dir/ || exit; shopt -s nullglob; shopt -s dotglob; count=(*); echo "${#count}"
```

In bash, without external tools and recursion.

```
shopt -s globstar; shopt -s dotglob 
for dir in **/*/; do 
  unset d f
  for files in "$dir"*; do 
    [[ -f $files ]] && ((++f))
    [[ -d $files ]] && ((++d))
  done; 
  printf '%s\n' "$dir -  files: ${f:-0} - directories: ${d:-0}"
done
```

Comment: Note that the second would follow symlinks when recursing (and count symlinks to regular files as regular files, and symlinks to dirs as dirs), would not count files and directories in the current directory and would not count `.` nor `..` entries. You may want to disambiguate file vs regular file.