# script to count files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, files, find

I'm looking for a script that counts files in the current directory (excluding sub directories). It should iterate through each file and if not a directory increment a count. The output should just be an integer representing the number of files.

I've come up with

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

But I don't really think it does the whole counting bit. This is for an assignment so if you only want point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: It's very close indeed. All you need is an extra operator to tell `find` not to descend into subdirectories. The `-maxdepth 1` will do that for you.

Comment: There's been some updates in the answers as to whether "hidden" files should count or not - do they? Also, `find`-based answers do not explicitly increment a counter -- is that a requirement?

Comment: … although the correct solution doesn’t appear until the last six lines of [slm’s answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101415/80216/how-to-use-wc-and-piping-to-find-how-many-files-and-directories-are-in-a-certain-directory#101418). Stéphane Chazelas also provides a very inclusive [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101415/80216#101442).

Answer (score 10):

If you want only regular files,

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

Other `find`s:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -print | grep -c /
```

(you don't want `-print | wc -l` as that wouldn't work if there are file names with newline characters).

With `zsh`:

```
files=(*(ND.)); echo $#files
```

With `ls`:

```
ls -Anq | grep -c '^-'
```

To include symlinks to regular files, change `-type f` to `-xtype f` with GNU `find`, or `-exec test -f {} \;` with other `find`s, or `.` with `-.` with `zsh`, or add the `-L` option to `ls`. Note however that you may get *false negatives* in cases where the type of the target of the symlink can't  be determined (for instance because it lies in a directory you don't have access to).

If you want any type of file (symlink, directory, pipes, devices...), not only regular one:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -printf . | wc -c
```

(change to `-print | grep -c /` with non-GNU `find`, `(ND.)` to `(ND)` with `zsh`, `grep -c '^-'` with `wc -l` with `ls`).

That will however not count `.` or `..` (generally, one doesn't really care about those as they are always there) unless you replace `-A` with `-a` with `ls`.

If you want all types of files except directories, Replace `-type f` with `! -type d` (or `! -xtype d` to also exclude symlinks to directories), and with `zsh`, replace `.` with `^/`, and with `ls`, replace `grep -c '^-'` with `grep -vc '^d'`.

If you want to exclude hidden files, add a `! -name '.*'` or with `zsh`, remove the `D` or with `ls`, remove the `A`.

Comment: [You mentioned](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299558/script-to-count-files-in-a-directory#comment527307_299562) that `grep -c /` is not guaranteed to work — so wouldn’t it be better, in your POSIX example, to do `-exec echo ";"` or `-exec dirname -- {} +`, and then count lines (with `wc -l`)?   Granted, the `dirname` example will crash and burn if the name of the *starting directory* contains newline(s) (e.g., `find $'foo\nbar' …`), but `! name .` assumes that you’re doing `find . …`, doesn’t it?   I would suggest `-exec stat -c "" -- {} +`, but `stat` isn’t in POSIX either (right?).

Comment: @G-Man, that's theoretical. POSIX leaves the behaviour of `grep` unspecified on non-text input. Here, it could be non-text if filenames contain non-characters (`LC_ALL=C` would work around that), or if the file paths are larger than LINE_MAX. Here for one level of directory, in practice, that won't happen. Even if that happened, in practice, what I see in implementations that have a LINE_MAX limit for `grep` is it only looking at the first LINE_MAX bytes of the line which is OK here as the / is in 2nd position.  That / would also appear before the first invalid character if any.

Comment: @G-Man, `stat` is the archetype of the non-portable command. And among the numerous incompatible implementations, the GNU one (which you seem to be refering to with that `-c` syntax) is one of the worst IMO (especially considering that GNU `find` had a much better interface (with the `-printf`syntax different from GNU `stat`'s (!?)) long before GNU `stat` was created. Here you could do `find . -exec printf '%.1s' {} + | wc -c`, but that potentially runs more commands than the `grep -c /` approach and is less efficient as it means holding the data and running potentially huge command lines.

Comment: I think `ls -A1 |wc -l` is a bit more intuitive for the ls options and will probably be a bit faster. Bring the steak sauce.

Comment: @flickerfly, that counts all directory entries but `.` and `..` not only  the regular files or non-directory files. That also doesn't work properly for file names with newline characters. Note that `-1` is superflous with POSIX compliant `ls` implementations.

Answer (score 3):

To exclude subdirectories

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

This assumes that none of the filenames contain newline characters, and that your implementation of find supports the `-maxdepth` option.

Comment: That doesn't work if there are filenames with newline characters. Replace `wc -l` with `grep -c /`. You can't assume a file path to be a line of text, you can't even assume it to be text at all as generally on Unix-like systems, file paths are just arrays of non-0 bytes, with nothing enforcing those bytes to form valid characters in the current locale. In that regard `grep -c /` is not even guaranteed to work (though in practice it generally does) as `grep` is only required to work properly on valid text.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas given that the context is an assignment this Answer is almost certainly sufficient.

Comment: @roaima, on the contrary, if that's about teaching, you want to teach the right thing and good practice. We don't want the next generation of coders making those incorrect assumption and write unreliable/vulnerable code.

Comment: Not sure of stackexchange etiquette, but choosing not to edit my answer in response to @StéphaneChazelas comment, as his own answer covers this improvement and more.

Comment: You could start the answer with _"If you can guarantee that none of the file names will contain newline characters, and assuming your `find` implementation supports the (non-standard) `-maxdepth` predicate"_. IOW, point out the limitations of the solution. My initial comment served that purpose, but if I've convinced you that it is indeed a limitation worth point out, then I'll be glad that you incorporate it in your answer to give it more visibility (no need to give credit (as far as _I_'m concerned)).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas when ones teaches, one starts with the basics and glosses over complexities. As an example in mathematics, young children are taught only integer arithmetic. As time progresses they are taught that only positive numbers have have a square root. Yet further on, one is introduced to _i_. By all means provide a professionally competent solution, but I urge that "sufficient" answers should also be offered, particularly when the asker explains that they are working on an (introductory) assignment. Unlike ServerFault we don't require a minimum standard of competence to participate.

Comment: @roaima. I don't agree. What first grades learn about arithmetic is correct. They don't learn that `1+1=2` only to learn later that it's incorrect and that they should forget about it. Here, `find . | wc -l` is incorrect or at least is only correct if you make some assumptions (which in practice you can rarely enforce). So, at the very least, those assumptions should be stated here. But IMO, it's better to teach a correct solution instead so people don't have to _unlearn_ what they've be taught before when they move to _a more advanced grade_.

Answer (score 3):

To *iterate* over everything in the current directory, use

```
for f in ./*; do
```

Then use either

```
[ -f "$f" ]
```

or

```
test -f "$f"
```

to test whether the thing you got is a regular file (or a symbolic link to one) or not.

Note that this will exclude files that are sockets or special in other ways.

To *just exclude directories*, use

```
[ ! -d "$f" ]
```

instead.

The quoting of the variable is important as it would otherwise miscount if there, for example, exists a directory called `hello world` and a file called `hello`.

To also match *hidden* files (files with a leading `.` in their filenames), either set the `dotglob` shell option with `shopt -s dotglob` (in `bash`), or use

```
for f in ./* ./.*; do
```

It may be wise also to set the `nullglob` shell option (in `bash`) if you want the shell to return nothing when these glob patterns match nothing (otherwise you'll get the literal strings `./*` and/or `./.*` in `f`).

Note: I avoid giving a complete script as this is an assignment.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. I think I fixed that now.

Comment: Quoting only disables the split+glob operator, it does nothing to change the meaning of `-` (unless `-` is in `$IFS`). `test -f -x` or `test -f "-x"` are the same thing (and are generally not a problem except in very old shells, but then you'd solve the problem with `for f in ./*`, not with quoting). Also note that `test -f hello world` would give you an error regardless of whether `hello` is a regular file or not (except in AT&T ksh)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I should write all of these things down... Thanks again! I'll remove the passage about `-` as I'm bypassing it with `./*`.

Comment: Why not use `dotglob` to match hidden files as well?

Comment: @KonradRudolph You know, that's a good suggestion. In my own scripts (and I rarely write `bash` scripts) I tend to not rely on `shopts` very much as they change the behaviour of basic things so radically. But in this case, just for doing this, it's a viable alternative. I'll mention it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize counter
count=0;

# go through the whole directory listing, including hidden files
for name in * .*
do
    if [[ ! -d $name ]]
    then
        # not a directory so count it
        count=$(($count+1))
    fi
done

echo $count
```

Comment: Just added support for hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that will handle files containing embedded newlines and other unprintable characters, this solution will work. But it's almost certainly overkill for your assignment.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c
```

What this does is to discard everything apart from the trailing `\0` at the end of each filename. It then counts those characters, which gives the number of files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script that will count up and then echo the number of (non-directory) files in the current directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=0
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for file in *
do
  [[ ! -d "$file" ]] && i=$((i+1))
done
echo "$i"
```

Setting "nullglob" gets the count right when there are no files (hidden or otherwise) in the current directory; leaving nullglob unset would mean that the `for` loop would (incorrectly) see one item: `*`.

Setting "dotglob" tells bash to also include hidden files (those start with a `.`) when globbing with `*`. By default, bash will not include `.` or `..` (see: [GLOBIGNORE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)) when generating the list of hidden files. If your assignment does not want to count hidden files, then do not set dotglob.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the simplest way **to count the files and directories** in the current directory is:

```
$ ls | wc -w
```

-w: is used to count words (not lines as the -l does) because ls outputs all files and directories as an empty-space separated list of words.

And **to count only the files** :
You can playing a little-bit with the marvelous `ls` flags you can get the directories out by adding a forward slash to directories `ls -p` make ls print the files in lines with `-l` and then invert `grep` to filter out the forward slashes:

```
$ ls -pl | grep -v '/' | wc -l
```

Comment: That last one will definitely be wrong if any filenames contains newlines. It will also count the "header" (`total NN`) that `ls -l` prints.

Comment: And the first if there are newlines or spaces in filenames.

Comment: True my friend I haven't thought of that!

Answer (score -3):

Your command will include sub-directories.

I'd go with:

```
count=0
for file in $(ls -a); do 
  if [ -f $file ]; then 
    count=$(expr $count + 1)
  fi
done
echo "There are $count files on $(pwd)"
```

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: @Kusalananda, `ls` only does (may do) that when the output goes to a tty device. Here, it's going to a pipe or socketpair depending on the shell. The issues would be more about filenames containing IFS or glob characters (try after `touch '*' 'a b'` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for putting me straight again.

Answer (score -3):

I usually stick to the `**ls**` command.
It gives me all kinds of possibilities.

A basic example :

```
ls | wc -l
```

Will list out the count of all files and directories in a path

```
ls -R | wc -l
```

Will list out the count of all files and directories in a path and its sub-directories.

```
ls -R *.log | wc -l
```

The count of only log files in the path and also all the sub-directories.

```
ls -la *.log | wc -l
```

Will give you only the log files count in the current directory and not sub-directories.

You limit here is your ls command

'ls' also gives us the ability to filter out files only by certain date, by file formats, and a lot more, using `wc` in par with 'ls', is possibly the best robust solution I would consider.

Have a look at 'man ls'

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: @Kusalananda, `ls -aq | wc -l` would be OK as then filenames are guaranteed to be on single lines (since a `\n` in the filename is rendered as `?`). So the first example is almost right. The rest have more issues.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My comment was in this case a comment on the _recommendation_ to use `ls` for these sort of things. It's not the tool for the job really.