# Print number of files excluding directories

Tags: directory, ls, wc

I learned that 'ls | wc -l' command prints number of files in the current directory, but it includes all files and directories.
Can I do the same task only for pure files excluding directories?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [script to count files in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299558)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*directory* is just one of many types of files. Other types include *symbolic link*, *fifo*, *device*, *regular*, *socket*...

In the output of `ls -n`, the first character indicates the type. `d` for directory, `-` for *regular*, `l` for *symlink*, so you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -Aqn | LC_ALL=C grep  -c '^-' # regular files only
LC_ALL=C ls -Aqn | LC_ALL=C grep -vc '^d' # anything but directory
```

(remove the `-A` option if you don't want to count hidden files).

You could also do the check *after symlink resolution*,

```
LC_ALL=C ls -LAqn | LC_ALL=C grep  -c '^-' # regular files or symlinks to regulars
LC_ALL=C ls -LAqn | LC_ALL=C grep -vc '^d' # anything but directory and symlinks to dirs.
```

With the `zsh` shell, you can also do it using globbing:

```
(){print $#} *(NDoN.)  # regular
(){print $#} *(NDoN^/) # non-directories
```

After symlink resolution (adding the `-` glob qualifier):

```
(){print $#} *(NDoN-.)  # regular
(){print $#} *(NDoN-^/) # non-directories
```

(remove the `D` qualifier if you don't want to count hidden files).

`oN` is to disable the sorting of the file list as an optimisation as we don't care about the order. The GNU implementation of `ls` has a `-U` option for that.

In any case, your `ls | wc -l` is wrong as it counts the number of newline characters used by `ls` to delimit the file names (so one per file), but also the newline  characters in the names of the file (it also omits hidden files). Using the `-q` option works around it as it causes newline characters in filenames to be rendered as `?`.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Beware that:

- this also count file names starting with `.`
- only looks at regular files (not fifo, symlinks etc)

Comment: That counts the number of lines in the file names, not the number of files. Use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  | LC_ALL=C grep -c /` to count the number of regular files. Also not that `-maxdepth` is a non-standard GNU extension. Use `find . ! -name . -prune -type f | LC_ALL=C grep -c /` posixly (equivalent of `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`)

Comment: that should be `| LC_ALL=C grep -c '^\./'` - otherwise you'll still count partial path-names with vertical spaces like linefeeds in directory names earlier in the path, like `./foo<LF>bar/bar<LF>foo/filename`.    Actually, even that regex can still be fooled by things like `./foo<LF>./bar/filename`

Comment: so use `find` with `-print0` and `grep -z -c ...` (GNU grep, maybe others too, i can't remember right now).   GNU `wc` also supports `--files0-from=-` for NUL-separated stdin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet able to post a comment but here is a bash-specific solution. It is not as succinct but might feel cleaner without the use of `grep`.

Since you used just `ls` I assume that you do not need hidden files.

```bsh
i=0
for f in *
do
[[ -f "$f" ]] && let "i++"
done
echo $i
```

Or combined into a one-liner, `i=0; for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && let "i++"; done; echo $i`

Comment: Note  that it counts *regular files* and *symlinks to regular files*, excluding hidden ones, so would be the equivalent of `zsh`'s `(){print $#} *(NoN-.)` or `ls -Lqn | LC_ALL=C grep -c '^-'`