# The result of "ls | wc -l" does not match the real number of files

Tags: linux, command-line, files, ls, wc

I need to count the number of files under a folder and use the following command.

```
cd testfolder
bash-4.1$ ls | wc -l
6
```

In fact, there are only five files under this folder,

```
bash-4.1$ ls
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 comp 11595 Sep  4 22:51 30.xls.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 comp 14492 Sep  4 22:51 A.pdf.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 comp  8160 Sep  4 22:51 comparison.docx.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 comp   903 Sep  4 22:51 Survey.pdf.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 comp  1206 Sep  4 22:51 Steam Table.xls.txt
```

It looks like `ls | wc -l` even counts the `total 44` as a file, which is not correct.

Comment: `wc -l` is working as it should.  Please run the command `type ls` and report what you see.

Comment: the result of "type ls" is  "ls is aliased to " ls  -cml"

Comment: It returns 6 because `wc -l` counts the number of lines... it's including the line that says `total 44`.

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line

Comment: also [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299558/170373) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101415/170373)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wc` is a char, word, and line counter, not a file counter.

You, the programmer/script writer, are responsible for making it count what you want and to adjust the calculation accordingly.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
echo $((`ls|wc -l`-1))
```

Finally note that your `ls` is probably an alias as it gives a long listing which is not the normal `ls` without arguments.  It may therefore be a good idea to refer to `ls`'s full path (usually `/bin/ls`) to avoid confusion.

Comment: If I use /bin/ls | wc -l  it will count 5 instead of 6

Comment: Also, echo $((`ls|wc -l`-1)) also give the correct count. Would you like to explain what does your command really do?

Comment: Of course.  I showed you 2 solutions to show you how you can deal with calculations in bash.

Comment: It subtracts 1 from the result of `wc` on your aliased `ls`.

Comment: If you put it in a script, it probably won't have the alias and as I mentioned it would be a better idea to use `/bin/ls|wc -l`.

Answer (score 12):

Just a extra info for the above,

You should use `find` instead of `ls` if you like to process the output, it has some futures which are more suitable (e.g. `-print0`) for piping the result to other applications.

In the above case you can use it like this,

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

which will list any **files** on the current directory.

Comment: why not use `-exec` instead of piping the result...

Comment: @spasic because that would count the lines inside each file instead of number of files

Comment: oops, good point :).. searching for `find + wc` gave this good Q&A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412244/use-find-wc-and-sed-to-count-lines

Comment: Will break if filename contains newline.

Comment: @123, in this uniq case you can use `find . -type f -print0 | wc --files0-from=-` which use `null` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 10):

It's not working because `wc -l` returns the number of lines of the output of the `ls` command, which in this case includes `total 44`. Since your shell has an alias for `ls` as `ls -cml`, you're getting that extra information which is messing up your output.

Instead, use the command `"ls" -Aq | wc -l`. The -A command lists all files in the directory including dotfiles, but excludes `.` and `..`. The quotations here are important - they ignore the alias and run `/bin/ls` directly.

`-q` makes sure that file names are all printed on one line only even if they contain newline characters (which would then be rendered as `?`).

Comment: Note that `"ls"` won't help if `ls` is defined as a _function_ instead of an _alias_ (or if there's also an alias for `"ls"` though that's less likely and not even supported by some shell). `command ls` may be more foolproof.

Comment: Hmm... on bash: `alias command="echo foo"`, `command ls`, outputs `foo ls`. Wonderful. At least it doesn't accept `/bin/ls` as an alias name.

Comment: I find `"ls"` a bit unclear. `/bin/ls` explicitly conveys what you are doing.

Comment: @ikkachu, the idea is that it's common to have a function for `ls` (like `ls() { [ ! -t 1 ] || set -- -F "$@"; command ls "$@"; }`), while it's uncommon for `command` to be an alias (except on AT&T ksh where `command` is a builtin alias)

Comment: you can also say `env ls`. `env` doesn't know about your shell aliases, functions etc., and if you call it like that it's a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, doing `ls | wc -l` is not always a reliable way to get files count in a directory.

Here are some reliable ways:

- You can get `find` to print a `.` for each file found and get `wc -l` to count the number of lines:

  ```
   find . -type f -printf '.\n' | wc -l
  ```
- If there are not many files in the directory, you can save the file names in an array and then get the length of the array:

  ```
   for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && files+=("$f"); done && echo "${#files[@]}"
  ```

  For all files and directories, this gets easier:

  ```
   files=( * ) && echo "${#files[@]}"
  ```

**Example:**

```
$ touch $'foo\nbar' 'foo bar' spam                         

$ ls | wc -l                      
4

$ find . -type f | wc -l                                   
4

$ find . -type f -printf '.\n' | wc -l
3

$ for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && files+=("$f"); done

$ echo "${#files[@]}"
3
```

Comment: @roaima you know what you just made me feel like a stupid now,  i don't know what i was thinking then.

Comment: @roaima I have made an edit. All credit goes to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash-4.1$ ls
1. total 44
2. -rw-r--r-- 1 comp 11595 Sep  4 22:51 30.xls.txt
3. -rw-r--r-- 1 comp 14492 Sep  4 22:51 A.pdf.txt
4. -rw-r--r-- 1 comp  8160 Sep  4 22:51 comparison.docx.txt
5. -rw-r--r-- 1 comp   903 Sep  4 22:51 Survey.pdf.txt
6. -rw-r--r-- 1 comp  1206 Sep  4 22:51 Steam Table.xls.txt
```

That's correct, there are 6 lines in the output. You might want to use: `ls -1` which corresponds to single column format and it looks like this:

```
ls -1
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
```

Now `wc -l` returns correct number of files:

```
ls -1 | wc -l
8
```

Comment: If you try `ls | cat` you'll see that `ls` automatically switches to `ls -1` format when talking to something that isn't a terminal. Unless it's been overridden with an alias that stops it doing so. (Which is what was happening to the OP.)